# Frequency-To-Voltage Convertor With LM2917

Tags: frequency-measurement, vf-fv-converter

I'm trying to make a frequency-to-voltage converter by using [LM2917](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1769108.pdf).

Its datasheet is very old and it doesn't explain function of the IC well. It just gives several example circuits and a formula for the output voltage. I want to learn working principle and internal circuit of the IC, and function of externally connected components (especially C41).

[image: example circuit in its datasheet]
An example circuit from the datasheet.

I understand that, the input opamp works as a comparator and converts the sinusoidal signal into digital pulses. The charge pump is charging a capacitor (which one?) at each pulse, so the output voltage level becomes somehow related to the pulse count in unit time. But how does this charge pump do this? All the capacitors and resistors are connected to ground; I'm very confused at this step. What is the function of the second opamp? It is drawn to be a comparator rather than a buffer. This is confusing too.

[image: my circuit with the IC]
(Vcc = 12V)

I need a circuit which generates 1mV voltage per 1Hz frequency. I created a custom library for this IC and set up my own circuit as seen in the schematics above. How do I choose value of C41 (I put a random one for now)?

Comment: In your calculation **"V_OUT = F_IN x (7.56V) x R46 x C40 = 1 mV/Hz"** I don't understand where you get 7.56V. I need 8 mV / Hz how can I adjust your calculation based on a 9V power supply (VCC)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd op-amp (feeding the BJT) isn't a comparator - it's a voltage follower - whatever voltage is on the +Vin input gets seen on the emitter of the BJT - notice the negative feedback from the emitter - it's a gain of unity buffer amp.

The first op-amp is a camparator as your question states.

Page 1 of the [data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snas555c/snas555c.pdf) says it all. \$V_{OUT} = F_{IN}\times R_1\times C_1\$ where \$R_1\$ and \$C_1\$ equate to your R46 and C40 on your 2nd drawing. This is the capacitor the charge pump is charging.

C42 does two things - the higher the value the lower the ripple voltage will be seen at the output however, the longer it will take to attain the correct voltage should the frequency change. Read towards the bottom of page 8 on the data sheet.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hand-waving explanation from a digital and software guy who has bumped in to sharp edges in the analog side... (**edit**: and a lesson for digital guys trying to second guess analog systems. I guessed the roles of the capacitors completely wrong initially. I've substantially edited this text to make it (more) true, see the edit history to see my incorrect babbling if you really want to.)

C40 is being charged by dumping charge into it at each zero crossing (or perhaps at one edge only) of the AC input. I'm guessing the AC input is required to be centered on 0V, incidentally, but a DC blocking cap outside the chip would easily achieve that. Since the chip was originally built to post-process a magnetic pickup for tachometer applications, the zero crossing would be easy to arrange for by directly wiring the pickup coil across pins 1 and 8.

R46 is acting as a load for the charged signal. The load is needed to convert the stored charge into a voltage that can be sensed, and pragmatically to provide a place for the stored charge to leak off into as frequency falls. The data sheet provides the detailed arithmetic, but the telling point is that the relationship between input frequency and output voltage only depends on C40 and R46.

C41 is a filter capacitor to reduce the ripple from the charge pump. You want it to keep the measurements stable.

The second op-amp is buffering the signal stored on C41 and driving the output transistor, it has feedback from the output to its -ve input which is a common configuration for a unit-gain buffer.

The output transistor is provided with open emitter and collector to permit its use in a variety of configurations. The datasheet indicates a typical use case for the chip being to light a warning light when input frequency exceeds a threshold, in which case having an output transistor capable of sourcing or sinking more current makes sense.

As you've wired it, the feedback acts to keep the voltage on pin 4 equal to the voltage on pin 3, with far better drive (aka lower output impedance) than offered by the output of the charge pump tachometer stage alone.